# OpenSSH Multiple connections to aws resources being closed with 'Connection to uniqueid.someregion1.elb.amazonaws.com closed by remote host.'

Tags: ssh, macos, aws

I have a script that generates multiple SSH tunnels to AWS resources via SSH alias that worked some time ago.

The connections are still created and authentication on to each is shown successful, but unfortunately **now** after about 1 min after creation (about 40+ connections) the connections start being closed with

```
Connection to uniqueid.someregion1.elb.amazonaws.com closed by remote host.
```

This same code did work some months back...key part looks like:

```bash
echo "Setting up tunnel from $IP:$LISTEN_PORT ---> to $DOMAIN:$LISTEN_PORT"
echo "$IP-$LISTEN_PORT" >> $TUNNELS/tunnels.lst
sudo ifconfig lo0 alias $IP up
sshcmd="sudo ssh -vvv -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o GlobalKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -i $PRIVATE_KEY_PATH -S $TUNNELS/tunnel-$IP_SUFF-$LISTEN_PORT.tnl -fMNL $IP:$LISTEN_PORT:$DOMAIN:$LISTEN_PORT $PRIVATE_KEY_PATH tunnel-$IP_SUFF-$LISTEN_PORT.tnl &"
```

Things I have tried:

- `/etc/ssh/sshd` settings (away from defaults):

  ```
  MaxStartups 200:200:200
  MaxSessions 200
  ```
- Setting my system clock to UTC hoping it matches the server...
- using `-vvv` for debug messages

No success so far.

Comment: Are you sure you wouldn’t be better served by a real VPN? OpenVPN is free and easy to set up. Even SSH has support for creating VPNs using the *tun* interface, see `ssh -w` parameter. With VPN you’ll only need one connection to access all your resources in the VPC.

Comment: @MLu - I don't know but since all my ssh tunnels get disconnected so that might not help